# Condicionar valores de un select para que muestre alumnos que integran un proyecto y alumnos que no estan suscritos a un proyecto

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una opcion para inscribir alumnos a un proyecto, anteriormente estaba el error de que se podian inscribir varias veces los alumnos o alumnos que aparecian en otros proyectos, por lo que cambie la consulta sql.

este formulario muestra el proyecto y abajo de el los alumnos que están inscritos en forma de lista *juan *pedro *luis.

Trabaja con tres tablas: Proyecto (proy_id), Alumno(cedu_alum) y Proyecto_alumno(proy_alum, alum_id)

Modifique el select para que tomara solo valores donde el proyecto estuviera nulo, pero ocurre que no muestra ya los alumnos inscritos a el proyecto, solo los que no lo estan, por lo que es imposible quitarlos,

Quisiera saber como modificar el select para que tambien mostrara los alumnos pertenecientes al proyecto que se esta modificando

Codigo del SELECT

```
function bd_alumno_opciones()
{
$sql = "SELECT cedu_alum, CONCAT(nom1_alum,' ',nom2_alum,' ',ape1_alum,'  ',ape2_alum,' ',cedu_alum)
FROM alumno LEFT JOIN proyecto_alumno ON cedu_alum = alum_id 
WHERE proy_id is null ORDER BY cedu_alum ASC";
$res = sql2options( $sql );
return $res;
}
```

Codigo para pasar el valor del proy_id al formulario de registro:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" onClick="return confirmSav();"    href="modificar_proyecto_alumno.php?proy_id=<?=$proyecto_alumno_temp['proy_id']?>">Modificar</a>
```

Formulario de modificar los alumnos:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"]==null){
print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido!\");window.location='login.php';    </script>";
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>.: UNEFA - Inscripción de Alumnos :.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php include "php/navbar.php"; ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Change es un evento que se ejecuta cada vez que se cambia el valor de un elemento (input, select, etc).
    $('#proyectos').change(function(e) {
      $('#proy_id').val($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>

<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$proy_id_seleccionado = ($_REQUEST['proy_id']);
$alumno = bd_alumno_opciones();
$proyecto = bd_proyecto_opciones();

include 'cab.php';
?>
<div>
<center>
<h1> Inscripción de Alumnos </h1>
<font size=3 color="red">*</font> <font size =3>Solo se permite que un alumno exista en un proyecto a la vez</font>
<font size=3 color="red">*</font> <font size =3>Campos Obligatorios</font>
</center>
</div>

<form id="frmIns" class="form-horizontal" method="POST"     action="proc_inscripcion4.php" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="proyectos" class="control-label col-lg-2"><font size=3     color="red">*</font>Proyecto:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">

        <select class="form-control" name="proyecto" id="proyectos">

        <?php foreach($proyecto as $i=>$proyecto_temp):?>
            <option value="<?=$i?>"><?=$proyecto_temp?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">

        <input type="hidden" name="proy_id" id="proy_id" readonly  value=""     />

    </div>
</div>



   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="alumno" class="col-lg-2 control-label"><font size=3 color="red">*</font>Alumnos:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <?php foreach($alumno as $i=>$alumno_temp): ?>
        <div class="checkbox"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="alum[]" id="alum_<?=$i?>" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$alumno_temp?></label></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Guardar</button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
<?php
include 'pie.php';
?>
<script src="./libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"     charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="./libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-    datetimepicker.es.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="./libs/jquery.chained.remote.min.js"></script>
<script src="./libs/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.form_date').datetimepicker({
    language:  'es',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 4,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0
});
 $("#frmIns").validate({
    rules: {
       proy_id: {
            required: true,
            range: [1, 9999]
        },
        alum_id: {
            required: true,
        },
    },
         messages: {
                proy_id: {
            required:"Seleccione un proyecto",
            range:"Seleccione un proyecto",
            }
        }
    });
 });

</script>
```

ERROR:

Warning: Missing argument 1 for bd_alumno_opciones(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema Automatizado de Registro y Control 2016\modificar_proyecto_alumno.php on line 23 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema Automatizado de Registro y Control 2016\conexion.php on line 350

Comment: Tu consulta, no es una pregunta, si no 3. Te sugiero revisar [¿Cómo hacer buenas preguntas?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y editar tu pregunta.

Comment: listo jejeje :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías agregar a la condición de la consulta que el valor del proyecto sea el que estás modificando además de que sea NULL.

Supongamos que tienes el código del proyecto a modificar en la variable $proy_id_seleccionado, el cual pasas como parámetro a la función .

```
function bd_alumno_opciones($proy_id_seleccionado){
 $sql = "SELECT cedu_alum,";
 $sql .= " CONCAT(nom1_alum,' ',nom2_alum,' ',ape1_alum,' ',ape2_alum,' ',cedu_alum) ";
 $sql .= " FROM alumno LEFT JOIN proyecto_alumno ON cedu_alum = alum_id ";
 $sql .= " WHERE proy_id = $proy_id_seleccionado OR proy_id is null ORDER BY cedu_alum ASC"; 
$res = sql2options( $sql ); 
return $res; }
```

**Nota**

Desconozco que utilizas para conectarte a la base de datos, pero se podría mejorar la consulta haciendo que sea una consulta preparada. Esto, entre otras cosas, te evitaría la inyección de código SQL.

Comment: si, lo de la inyeccion ya varios me lo han comentado, y pues me queria centrar primero en agregarles las funciones que debe tener el sistema, y luego ir mejorando eso. el proy_id lo podria sacar de la select list que publicare ahorita?

Comment: Entiendo que el proy_id proviene de la acción de elegir modificar los miembros del proyecto (hay infinidad de maneras de hacerlo).

Comment: Por eso lo agrego como nota lo de inyección de código SQL, no responde a tu pregunta, pero no puedo no mencionartelo.

Comment: entonces lo podria tomar de la caja de texto hidden que el ajax llena, cierto

Comment: exacto, muchas gracias, luego podria ir posteando el archivo de conexion para corregir los sql

Comment: por cierto cual es la difrencia de hacer todos esos sql que hacer uno solo?

Comment: Legibilidad nomas.

Comment: lo agregue pero me da error, a pesar de que al darle modificar en la lista de los proyectos este me pasa el proy_id, posteare el codig

Comment: Esta línea? $alumno = bd_alumno_opciones(); Te falta pasarle el parámetro a la función.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45337/discussion-between-victor-alejandro-alvarado-vilo-and-el-asiduo).

Comment: Asiduo necesito tu ayuda, me ocurrio un problema con estta funcion.

http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36815/modificar-formula-para-que-funcione-sin-tener-un-id-previo