# Usar funcion de seleccion con un parametro determinado y sin parametro

Tags: php, sql

Poseo un sistema para registrar alumnos a proyectos que tiene una universidad (tabla proyectos), los cuales no deben estar en otro proyecto.

Este sistema me permite ver un listado con los alumnos que tienen la capacidad de ser inscritos para inscribirlos, antes mostraba incluso los que ya estaban en proyectos, por lo que consegui la siguiente funcion

```
function bd_alumno_opciones($proy_id_seleccionado){
$sql = "SELECT cedu_alum,";
$sql .= " CONCAT(nom1_alum,' ',nom2_alum,' ',ape1_alum,' ',ape2_alum,' ',cedu_alum) ";
 $sql .= " FROM alumno LEFT JOIN proyecto_alumno ON cedu_alum = alum_id ";
 $sql .= " WHERE proy_id = $proy_id_seleccionado OR proy_id is null ORDER BY cedu_alum ASC"; 
$res = sql2options( $sql ); 
return $res; }
```

Esta permite mostrar los que no estan inscritos en otro proyecto, el problema radica en que solo funciona a la hora de querer modificar un proyecto para agregar o eliminar alumnos, pero cuando quiero inscribirlos me da error, porque no existe la variable que los compara

USO MYSQL

quisiera poder tener una funcion que muestre los que no estan con proyectos para inscribirlos, y que tambien me sirva para modificar un proyecto tomando ese ID del proyecto

TABLA ALUMNOS

```
CREATE TABLE `alumno` (
`cedu_alum` int(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'CÃ©dula',
`ape1_alum` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`ape2_alum` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`nom1_alum` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`nom2_alum` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`fech_naci` date NOT NULL,
`telf_resi_alum` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`telf_celu_alum` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`emai_alum` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`carr_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
`seme_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
`pera_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
`peri_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
`capa_id` int(1) NOT NULL
```

TABLA PROYECTOS

```
CREATE TABLE `proyecto` (
`proy_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`proy_deno` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`plan_proy` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`objg_proy` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`obje_proy` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`fech_insc` date NOT NULL,
`nomb_comu` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`resp_comu` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`parr_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
`deta` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`esta_proy_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
`telf_inst` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`telf_resp` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`obsv_proy` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`proy_carr_id` int(2) NOT NULL
```

TABLA PROYECTO_ALUMNO

```
CREATE TABLE `proyecto_alumno` (
`proy_alum_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`proy_id` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`alum_id` int(9) NOT NULL
```

RESULTADO DE CONSULTA EN INSCRIBIR ALUMNO

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for bd_alumno_opciones(), called in     C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema Automatizado de Registro y Control 2016\registro4.php on     line 37 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema Automatizado de Registro y     Control 2016\conexion.php on line 342
Notice: Undefined variable: proy_id_seleccionado in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema    Automatizado de Registro y Control 2016\conexion.php on line 347
```

RESULTADO DESEADO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

POR CIERTO APLIQUE LA FUNCION DE: Eduardo Fuentes
y ahora muestra lo que deseo pero sigue diciendo que falta una variable.

La linea de codigo que da error es la funcion que esta arriba

FORMULARIO DE INSCRIPCION:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$proy_id_seleccionado= 0;
$alumno = bd_alumno_opciones();
$proyecto = bd_proyecto_opciones();
<form id="frmIns" class="form-horizontal" method="POST"   action="proc_inscripcion4.php" role="form">



        <select class="form-control" name="proyecto" id="proyectos">

        <?php foreach($proyecto as $i=>$proyecto_temp):?>
            <option value="<?=$i?>"><?=$proyecto_temp?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">

        <input type="hidden" name="proy_id" id="proy_id" readonly  value="" />

    </div>
</div>



   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="alumno" class="col-lg-2 control-label"><font size=3 color="red">*</font>Alumnos:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <?php foreach($alumno as $i=>$alumno_temp): ?>
        <div class="checkbox"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="alum[]" id="alum_<?=$i?>" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$alumno_temp?></label></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>




<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Guardar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece entender la pregunta.
Tienes esta función que actualmente devuelve los alumnos que no pertenecen a un proyecto en específico identificado por el parámetro de entrada $proy_id_seleccionado. Y quieres ocupar la misma función para inscribir alumnos, momento en que te estorba el parámetro incluido en la query. Personalmente yo preferiría usar otra función que realizara el trabajo que necesitas, pero si prefieres hacerlo con la misma función podrías enviar el parámetro de entrada en 0 cuando vayas a inscribir alumnos, y luego modificar el código para obviar la parte del parámetro si es que éste viene en 0.

```
function bd_alumno_opciones($proy_id_seleccionado){
  $sql = "SELECT cedu_alum,";
  $sql .= " CONCAT(nom1_alum,' ',nom2_alum,' ',ape1_alum,' ',ape2_alum,' ',cedu_alum) ";
  $sql .= " FROM alumno LEFT JOIN proyecto_alumno ON cedu_alum = alum_id ";
  $sql .= " WHERE proy_id is null";
  if ( $proy_id_seleccionado != 0 ){
    $sql .= " OR proy_id = $proy_id_seleccionado";
  }
  $sql .= " ORDER BY cedu_alum ASC"; 
  $res = sql2options( $sql ); 
  return $res;
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Lo unico que necesito es que tanto al inscribir, como al modificar el proyecto muestre unicamente los alumnos que no estan inscritos ya, esto se logra porque hay una tabla anidada que tiene ID del alumno e ID del proyecto, entonces por eso esta la comparacion si en la tabla no esta el ID del alumno esta disponible, sino esta inscrito ya.

No se que funcion podrias tener, puedes yo use ese parametro $proy_id_seleccionado para modificar, pero no me habia dado cuenta de que habia dañado la funcion principal de inscribir

Comment: Victor, sigues teniendo un error ya que tu función necesita que le ingreses un parámetro, y en el código de inscripción de alumno la estás llamando sin parámetros, bd_alumno_opciones(), en el caso de la inscripción de alumno deberías llamarla de la siguiente manera: bd_alumno_opciones( 0 ). El código que te pasé verá que es un 0 y sabrá que no debe buscar con el id de proyecto.

Comment: a ok, habia declarado el cero en otra parte jejejej,muchas gracias, entonces sigue esa funcion haciendo lo mismo, mostrando solo los alumnos que no estan en proyectos verdad?

Comment: PERFECTO FUNCIONA EXCELENTE MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!

Comment: Una duda adicional, no se si debe crear pregunta para ello, como agrego un mensaje que diga "no hay alumnos disponibles" pues solo muestra arriba la lista de proyectos y luego un cuadro en blanco